# How to create temp table in postgresql with values and empty column

Tags: sql, postgresql, temp-tables

I am very new to postgresql. I want to create a temp table containing some values and empty columns. Here is my query but it is not executing, but gives an error at `,` (comma).

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 
AS (
 SELECT distinct region_name, country_name 
 from opens 
 where track_id=42, count int)
```

What did I do wrong?

How to create a temp table with some columns that has values using select query and other columns as empty?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just select a NULL value:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 
AS
SELECT distinct region_name, country_name, null::integer as "count"
from opens 
where track_id=42;
```

The cast to an integer (`null::integer`) is necessary, otherwise Postgres wouldn't know what data type to use for the additional column. If you want to supply a different value you can of course use e.g. `42 as "count"` instead

Note that `count` is a reserved keyword, so you have to use double quotes if you want to use it as an identifier. It would however be better to find a different name.

There is also no need to put the `SELECT` statement for an `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` between parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes form your statement near the clause WHERE.

This should work :

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 AS 
(SELECT distinct region_name, 
        country_name,
        0 as count 
 FROM   opens 
 WHERE track_id=42)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
            CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 AS 
            (SELECT distinct region_name, 
                    country_name,
                    cast( '0' as integer) as count
             FROM   opens 
             WHERE track_id=42);
```

Comment: `cast( '0' as integer)` can be simplified to `0`

Comment: Yes. IT can be.